# How to fix MongoError: unsupporter server version?

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, express, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a Node.js server with MongoDB. I followed the tutorials closely. Here is my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const asser = require('assert');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
var db;

app.listen(80, () => {
  console.log('listening on 80')
})
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database

})

app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  console.log("asdf");

  res.send('1');
  port.write(JSON.stringify(req.body) + "\n");

});

function onOpen() {
  console.log("OPENED");
}

function onData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

`
When I try to run it, however, I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Server $ sudo node app.js
listening on 80
{ MongoError: unsupported server version
at /home/pi/Server/node_modules/mongodb-
core/lib/topologies/server.js:367:39
at /home/pi/Server/node_modules/mongodb-
core/lib/connection/pool.js:542:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) name: 
'MongoError', message: 'unsupported server version' }
```

How can I fix this? My package.json file says I am using version ^3.0.0-rc0. I cant seem to find a solution anywhere online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of MongoDB. The database system, not the driver that is listed in package.json.

You also have to update your connection code slightly:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database

})
```

should be

```
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = client.db('test')
})
```

That's because the syntax changed somewhat for version 3.0.0 of the mongodb driver.